# iMac causes WiFi interference / outage

Tags: network, wifi, airport, router

I have an Apple Airport Extreme WiFi router and three wireless clients (iPhone, MacBook Pro & iMac).

The iPhone and a MacBook Pro are connected to the WiFi network and everything works fine. As soon as I join the WiFi with the iMac, all three lose Internet connectivity and the ping times for external sites go to ~100,000ms at which point the network becomes unusable.

As soon as I shut the WiFi on the iMac off, the network returns to normal. What's interesting is that my WiFi base station has two SSIDs, one private network one guest network. It doesn't matter which network I join with the iMac, both cause the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same wifi issues with two iMacs, one iPhone, one android... the iMacs were the problem. This worked for me:

[Resolving Stubborn Wi-Fi Connection Problems in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/30/resolving-stubborn-wi-fi-connection-problems-in-mac-os-x/)

I hope it does for you.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by changing Location under preferences from Automatic to a new location.  Thanks